# Mask sensitive data via annotation using log4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

I use log4j2 in my Spring Boot project. When log event happens I want to mask sensitive data in my DTO using annotation, for example:

```
@Sensitive(fields = {password, email})
public class MyDTO {

   private String name;
   private String email;
   private String password

}
```

I want to have opportunity to set fields to mask in annotation props.

I tried to use custom serialiser for this, but I do not want to  mask data every time when I serialise my DTO, only when logging event happens.

I tried to apply RewritePolicy, but in this case I already have logging message as String and I can't access class to grab annotation params to know what fields should be masked.

It would be grate to handle log event before myDto.toString() method invoked, get annotation from class, check fields to mask and replace them before set log message.

Could you please help me?

Comment: If this is passed as object in log4j logger it will just call toString. So unless you write an Aspect that intercepts the `toString` methods for `@Sensitive` marked classes this isn't going to work. You would need to embed it into the `toString` method (or maybe a custom appended in Log4j that could do the trick).

Comment: Or just make sure the toString does not contain sensitive data. So rather than the Sensitive annotation, perhaps use the Lombok `@ToString` annotation so you can specify there which fields to exclude.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thx you for advice! I haven't think about using aspects yet. I will Try to solve my problem by applying aspect. Could you give me advice what framework would be better for this - Spring AOP or AspectJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am also looking like same... have extra requirement like if mobileNumber fields we have to mask first 5 characters

As of my knowledge

we can mask fields using log4j configuration file.
https://objectpartners.com/2017/09/26/masking-sensitive-data-in-log4j-2/